# Why is this limit same as this limit

Tags: limits

This is a quick question but it is bothering me for some time, so why is this limit same as this?

[image]

thanks!

Comment: $\ln a^b=b \ln a$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Fix the & to a $ and I'll upvote.

Comment: Oh yes , thank you

Comment: $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=\frac{1}{x}\cdot\ln{(1+x)}=\ln{(1+x)}^{\frac{1}{x}}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties of logs
$\ln x^a = a\ln x$

Comment: I must wait 4 minutes to accept the answer